# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I try to upgrade the android.support:support. but it showing some error:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources]
    :app:preBuild
    :app:preDebugBuild
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Rc1Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Rc1Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    :app:processDebugManifest
    /home/ti/Projectname/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:


Error:/home/ti/Projectname/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 11 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 11 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved for me :

I had make canges in these lines.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 20
   buildToolsVersion '20'

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 11
       targetSdkVersion 20
       versionCode 6
       versionName "1.1"
   }
   .
   .
   .

 }

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
  ....
}
```

NOTE: If you didn’t update the android studio latest version,update it first.

try this if you didn't resolved.

Comment: What exactly is the change? Can you please highlight the change in your build.gradle please? Thank you

Comment: @Ahmed After update sdk to 20 W I upgrade the dependencies to 0.11 to 0.12 and compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion to 20 and appcompat and support to 20.

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't work for me. Its unable to find 20 because under the sdk -> buildtools folder 20 W folder name is different. i.e. android 4.4W, which is unidentifiable. Can you please share the name of the last buildtool you have in your sdk->buildtools folder?

Comment: Android SDK platform tool 20 ,Android SDK Build tool 20 ,Android 4.4W -SDK platform and Source for Android SDK there all i installed